# Difference-in-Differences with Multiple Time Periods: 'Always treated' group?

Tags: regression, r, difference-in-difference, epidemiology

The title of the post refers to this paper by Callaway & Sant'Anna: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304407620303948?via%3Dihub

Let us assume that I have data on incidence ratio per 1000 person-years of cardiovascular disease (CVD), by census tract and year, in a city, for the period 1990-2020.

Let us assume that I want to estimate the dynamic effects of the construction of large urban parks on the incidence of CVD diseases. To do this, I make an as-if random assignment of census tracts to the intervention group based on a buffer distance from the intervention (tracts falling within the buffer enter the intervention group in the corresponding year). This is clearly a staggered intervention, as parks will be built in different parts of the city at different points in time. Many census tracts do not receive the intervention ('never treated' units), as they do not fall within the specified buffer area. However, if a park has been built, say, since 1980, the units within the buffer area will constitute 'always treated' units.
I have not seen a description of this problem in the literature, unlike in the case of 'never treated' units (e.g., it is described in this example from Callaway & Sant'Anna: https://bcallaway11.github.io/did/articles/did-basics.html).

What would be the best approach for estimating dynamic effects? Should these census tracts be excluded from the analysis?

Comment: Welcome. There are a couple of ways to handle the "always treated" units. Out of curiosity, were any parks or playgrounds demolished or used for other purposes during the observation period? In other words, do any of the tracts that begin as treated become untreated later?

Comment: @ThomasBilach Thank you. I understand your point, as this is a common scenario in natural experimentation studies of this kind, but this is not the case. The main concern would therefore be the 'always treated' units. What would be that couple of ways of dealing with this issue?